# TextView does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that plays the role of a row item of a listView. The layout has a textview and an edittext as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemFlightNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="test test test test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/busNumberEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that the **textView does not wrap_content**. If i remove the edittext, textView wraps content properly so **it's a fault of edittext's existance**. Any help on the reason why layout has this behavior ?

Comment: can you elaborate more.whats your exact issue

Comment: @Narute, The issue is that the textview does not wrap the content, this layout goes out for layout_normal, when the content of textview is long enough, the height of row's view is smaller than textview's height, thus the context of textview is not entirely visible. (The second row is cut in the middle). If you are able to put the code on an IDE (android studio) you can see the effect.

Comment: @bachu, The weight is used for the width parameter of views, the issue is with the height that is not affected by the weight value.

Answer (score 2):

try to put match_parent in the textView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemFlightNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="test test test test"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Comment: How can that work ? Textview have to wrap the content, not match parent.
But parent has height="wrap_content", so what value will have the height of textview. Is there a trick on this ? (because it seems to work)

Comment: It's like pulling yourself up by your bootstraps. The TextView needs to be as wide as its parent container, and the parent container needs to resize to fit the TextView, and somehow that circular logic solves the problem instead of leading to a stack overflow crash... lol.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @Sifis , please accept it. It's also undocumented, so, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to add to `TextView`

```
android:width="0dip"
```

it helped me

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` in `android:orientation="horizontal"` will override width of its child views if child views have `android:layout_weight` tag.

So remove `android:layout_weight` from child views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemFlightNameTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="test test test test"
    android:singleLine="false"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/busNumberEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemFlightNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="test test test test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/busNumberEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please Try this

Comment: I don't want textview to be singlelined to let the user be able to see the whole content of textview. "Ellipsize" was a good idea, but didn't fix the issue..

Comment: then remove ellipsize and single line

Comment: If u want to show text view and edit in same line it will like tat only.. pls tell me how u want give me some screen shot